# Serial Port communication is Freezing while dragging the widget

Tags: c++, qt

i made an application which receives the serial port data ( which is threaded using QThread) continuously

But the problem is when ever i drag the widget . Am loseing somedata i.e at that time the logic entirely freezes .

i suspect that main gui thread which will run bydefault by Qt is not giving focus to my Running thread . So how do i solve this problem

Such that even if i drag the window also i should not loose the data .

In Later Stage i have to do one Camera App using opencv so for that as well the same problem might occur .

I have give a small logic of my program .

What can be the solution for this

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    m_ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    m_status(new QLabel),
    m_console(new Console),
    m_settings(new SettingsDialog),
    //! [1]
    m_serial(new QSerialPort(this))
{


LoggerThread = new QThread( );
    MyLogger = new MyTerminalLogger( );
    MyLogger->moveToThread(LoggerThread);
    LoggerThread->start();

    connect(MyLogger,SIGNAL (Send_Accelerometer_Processed_Data(unsigned short,double,double,double,double)),this,SLOT(Process_AND_Plot_Accelerometer_Data(unsigned short,double ,double ,double ,double )));


}

void MainWindow::openSerialPort()
{
    const SettingsDialog::Settings p = m_settings->settings();
    m_serial->setPortName(p.name);
    m_serial->setBaudRate(p.baudRate);
    m_serial->setDataBits(p.dataBits);
    m_serial->setParity(p.parity);
    m_serial->setStopBits(p.stopBits);
    m_serial->setFlowControl(p.flowControl);
    if (m_serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        m_console->setEnabled(true);
        m_console->setLocalEchoEnabled(p.localEchoEnabled);
        m_ui->actionConnect->setEnabled(false);
        m_ui->actionDisconnect->setEnabled(true);
        m_ui->actionConfigure->setEnabled(false);
        showStatusMessage(tr("Connected to %1 : %2, %3, %4, %5, %6")
                          .arg(p.name).arg(p.stringBaudRate).arg(p.stringDataBits)
                          .arg(p.stringParity).arg(p.stringStopBits).arg(p.stringFlowControl));
    } else {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), m_serial->errorString());

        showStatusMessage(tr("Open error"));
    }
}
//! [4]

//! [5]
void MainWindow::closeSerialPort()
{
    if (m_serial->isOpen())
        m_serial->close();
    m_console->setEnabled(false);
    m_ui->actionConnect->setEnabled(true);
    m_ui->actionDisconnect->setEnabled(false);
    m_ui->actionConfigure->setEnabled(true);
    showStatusMessage(tr("Disconnected"));
}
//! [5]

void MainWindow::about()
{
    QMessageBox::about(this, tr("About Simple Terminal"),
                       tr("The <b>Simple Terminal</b> example demonstrates how to "
                          "use the Qt Serial Port module in modern GUI applications "
                          "using Qt, with a menu bar, toolbars, and a status bar."));
}

//! [6]
void MainWindow::writeData(const QByteArray &data)
{
    m_serial->write(data);
    qDebug()<<" Writing "<<data;
}
//! [6]

//! [7]
void MainWindow::readData()
{
    const QByteArray data = m_serial->readAll();


    MyLogger->Process_TerminalData(data);
    m_ui->listWidget->clear();
    m_ui->listWidget->addItem(data);


}
```

Comment: The action of receiving data in your code is done in MainWindow which is on main thread. You should also read data on your worker thread to prevent data loss.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mr nejat , but i  just want to know what is making this to happen becoz i have another app where i am doing the VideoCapture of webcam and using namedwindow and imshow am displaying the image and all these are inside a seaperate thread but still when i drag the widget still i have the same issue . so can we say Main thread which is run by Qt to run independently ?

Comment: @MrVin The code you posted isn't sufficient to say what your threading model is; and it's going to end up being not minimal if you post the lot.  However, it seems very likely that your understanding of the threading model isn't right.  I would suggest you put a break point in the read/write functions and demonstrate to yourself that your UI thread never enters them and then go from there.

Comment: @MrVin Obviously another issue with your code is that you are directly calling the function `Process_TerminalData` of your object which is in another thread. Instead you should pass data by emitting a signal which is connected to the desired slot.

Comment: Thank you Nejat it solved my problem . Instead of calling the method directly now am emiting a signal and based on that am calling that method using SIGNAL SLOT Mechanism .